# Split a single column into multiple rows in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to transform a single cell in a column into several rows. What technique or DAX should I use in PowerBI to achieve the result.

The table is details are given below,

```
    +------------------------------------------------+----------------+
    |                      Time                      |     Status     |
    +------------------------------------------------+----------------+
    | TimeStamp (2019-01-02, 2019-01-03, 2019-01-04) | (Yes, Yes, No) |
    +------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

I wanted a output like this,

```
    +------------+----------+
    |    Time    |  Status  |
    +------------+----------+
    | 2019-01-02 | Yes      |
    | 2019-01-03 | Yes      |
    | 2019-01-04 | No       |
    +------------+----------+
```

I have tried several solution and not able to attain a conclusion on PowerBI.

Comment: Please share the several solutions that you tried so the community can help you instead of doing it for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In my opinion, this is not a job for DAX.  I would do it in Power Query.  There you will find pivot/unpivot along with columnar splits and merges that will make this a lot easier to digest.

Comment: Please confirm if one of the answers helped you by checking "Answered"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used both powerquery and DAX to solve this problem

First I have created book1 to get the status column and split column by (,) using row delimited option instead of column delimited and added index to it. Then book2 table created to get only the Time column and split column by (,) using same row delimited option and added index to it.

Book 1: Powerquery

`let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\PremChand\Desktop\stack\Book1.csv"),Delimiter=",", Columns=2, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Promoted Headers","TimeStamp","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Time"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","(","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Time", "Status"}),
    #"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value1",")","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Time", "Status"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value2", {{"Status", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Status"),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Index",{"Time"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Index", "Index1"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"`

Book 2: Powerquery

`let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\PremChand\Desktop\stack\Book1.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=2, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Promoted Headers","TimeStamp","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Time"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","(","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Time", "Status"}),
    #"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value1",")","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Time", "Status"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value2", {{"Time", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Time"),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Index",{"Status"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"`

Once book1 and book2 has created relationship has created for both Index column. Then the new output table has created using DAX to join book1 and book2.

Below DAX used to join two tables:

`Output = NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN(Book2,Book1)`

The Output table consist of Time, Status and Index and Index1 column you can select only Time and status column to show in a table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to use Power Query. Open the advanced editor and past the code below. You need to edit the part where you get the data:

```
let
    GetData = (test as record) => let
        textTimeStamp = Text.BetweenDelimiters(test[TimeStamp], "(", ")"),
        tableTimeStamp = Table.FromList(Function.Invoke(Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(","), {textTimeStamp}),null,{"TimeStamp"}),
        tableTimeStampIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(tableTimeStamp, "Index"),

        textAnswer = Text.BetweenDelimiters(test[Answer], "(", ")"),
        tableAnswer = Table.FromList( Function.Invoke(Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(","), {textAnswer}),null,{"Answer"}),
        tableAnswerIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(tableAnswer, "Index"),

        joinedTable = Table.Join(tableTimeStampIndex, "Index", tableAnswerIndex, "Index"),
        removeIndex = Table.RemoveColumns(joinedTable,{"Index"})
    in
        removeIndex,


    TimeSplit = let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\...\Documents\TimeSplit.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=2, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in
    #"Promoted Headers",
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(TimeSplit, "ToList", each GetData(_)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Invoked Custom Function",{"TimeStamp", "Answer"}),
    #"Expanded ToList" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "ToList", {"TimeStamp", "Answer"}, {"TimeStamp", "Answer"})
in
    #"Expanded ToList"
```